Conceptual misunderstanding in Cauchy's equation in optics
We know that Cauchy's equation in optics is refractive index n = A + B/lambda^2 + c/lambda^4+ .... . But we also know that in any medium n = lambda in freespace/lambda in medium i.e n = A/lambda. What am I missing?

Let $\lambda_{c}$ denote the lambda in free space, and let $\lambda_{m}$ denote the lambda in medium.
Now, under the Cauchy's equation, we have:
$$
n = A + \frac{B}{\lambda_{c}^2} + \frac{C}{\lambda_{c}^4} + ...
$$
And, under the second equation you've provide, is:
$$
n = \frac{\lambda_{c}}{\lambda_{m}}
$$
Actually and usually, we should use the first formula to calculate the refractive index, and then use the second formula to calculate the wavelength in the medium. That's the logical order of things...

By the way, the Cauchy's equation is an approximation result of the dispersion theory. If you need more impressively understanding, please refer to the book: Principles of Optics by Born, where the section 2.3 gives a detailed explanation.
More fundamentally, the refractive index is not directly about the wavelength $\lambda_{c}$ but frequency $\nu$. On the basis of the $n(\nu)$, we use the identity $\nu=\frac{c}{\lambda_{c}}$ to derive the relation between refractive index and wavelength, i.e. $n(\lambda_{c})$.

Thank you, got it.
